# ¿Como llenar un objeto de objetos, javascript?

Tags: jquery

Estoy intentando armar el siguiente objeto

```
objeto: "D1": { 
            "C60": true, 
            "C80": true 
        }
```

que contiene contiene otro objeto.
Lo realizo de la siguiente forma:

```
permisosCuponesSeleccionados["usuario"] = "D1
console.log(permisosCuponesSeleccionados);
```

El problema es que siempre creo el mismo objeto.
Como puedo ir creando multiples objetos dentro de ese objeto.

Comment: Un objeto es una estructura que usa llaves así `{"D1": .....}`. Tu sólo estás asignando una cadena de caracteres "D1".

Answer (score 1):

Explicándote que los objetos en javascript son una forma de guardar múltiples datos, tanto como `string`, `boolean`, `int`, `float`, etc.

Puedes crear un objeto llamado **celular**, el celular tiene tres o más datos, unos de ellos son color, marca, capacidad.

> El `color` puede variar, puede ser negro y gris a la vez, podemos
>   armarlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
var celular = {
  color: ['negro', 'gris'],
  marca: 'iPhone',
  capacidad: 64
}

console.log(celular)
```

Como podemos ver en el objeto `celular.color` hay y mas de un dato, pueden ser mas si quieres.

```js
var celular = {
  color: ['negro', 'gris'],
  marca: 'iPhone',
  capacidad: 64
}

console.log(celular.color)
```

Pero podemos agregar mas datos a mi objeto `celular`, podemos agregar `modelo`.

```js
var celular = {
  color: ['negro', 'gris'],
  marca: 'iPhone',
  capacidad: 64
}

celular.modelo = '6S'

console.log(celular)
```

De esta manera modificamos nuestro objeto agregándole un nuevo dato llamado modelo, este dato es un `string`, podemos agregarle otro dato que sea un objeto..

```js
var celular = {
  color: ['negro', 'gris'],
  marca: 'iPhone',
  capacidad: 64
}

celular.modelo = '6S'

var aplicaciones = [
  {
    nombre: 'whatsapp',
    peso: 120,
  },
  {
    nombre: 'facebook',
    peso: 160,
  }
]

celular.aplicaciones = aplicaciones

console.log(celular)
```

> **De esta manera agregamos una lista de objetos en un objeto.**

Comment: Estimado como podría ir agregando un objeto dentro de un objeto de forma dinamica. Digamos al presionar un boton que ejecute una funcion que vaya agregando un objeto dentro de otro objeto principal. Puede ser cualquier valor lo que me interesa es realizarlo de forma dinamica. De antemano muy agradecido por tu respuesta.